# How to get all classes with attributes?

Tags: c#, .net

I have class

```
[CommandPrefix("-t")]
[CommandPrefix("--thread")]
public class ThreadSelectCommand : ICommand
{
}
```

and I need to get this class in Main method with using attributes `("-t")` from `string[] args`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // How?
}
```

What I need to use?

Comment: What do you mean by getting this class? Do you want to get the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe I understood your query correctly. You would like to search classes which has an `CommandPrefixAttribute` decorated and with the value *"-t"*, which is passed via args (let's call this property within the attribute as Prefix for sake of example)

Assuming you have a property called `Prefix` in the declaration of `CommandPrefixAttribute` (as defined below).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CommandPrefixAttribute:Attribute
{
    public string Prefix {get;set;}
    public CommandPrefixAttribute(string prefix)
    {
        Prefix = prefix;
    }
}
```

You could find the Classes which has the specified attribute with property Prefix set as "-t". (Query could be more than one if more than one class is decorated with `CommandPrefix("-t)`).

```
var assembly = typeof(ThreadSelectCommand).Assembly;
var commands = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.GetCustomAttributes<CommandPrefixAttribute>().Any(c=>c.Prefix.Equals(prefixToSearch)));
```

If there are more than one class which matches the query, depending on the logic of your application, you need to choose the ideal one.

**Update** (Based on comment)

To get all classes that implements an Interface, you could use the following.

```
var commands = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x=>typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface);
```

Comment: You have two `Any()`, which is uneccessary. You should have only the last.

Comment: @AnuViswan What if I need to find all classes that realize interface ICommand?

Comment: @GregorySysoev Pls check the answer now. I misread your comment earlier.